# How to play multiple files in a folder with VoiceXML?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, voicexml

For a specific project, I am trying to write a voicexml file to play out some audio files. I have no problem about playing an file. But I need some directions for playing multiple files in a folder. I know I have to use ecmascript and  tag to do this. But I can't figure out how to access a folder to play the specific wav files.

Here is my code to play 1 audio file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<vxml version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" xml:base="file://">
<var name="repeat" expr="session.user.repeat"/>
<form id="loopblock">
    <block>
        <if cond="repeat > 0">
        <prompt>
            <audio src="file://provisioned/music.wav"/>
        </prompt> 
        <assign name="repeat" expr="repeat - 1"/>
        <goto next="#loopblock"/>
        </if>
        <disconnect/>
    </block>
</form>
</vxml>
```

I have a folder which includes different .wav files.

- /provisioned/music/a.wav
- /provisioned/music/b.wav
- /provisioned/music/c.wav

How can I play all of them without calling them one by one because anyone can customize this wav file. All I need to scan the folder and play them out with VoiceXML.

I'd be appreciated for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At First, VoiceXML can't scan the folder.
It needs other programming language.

For example(JSP - http://localhost:8080/example/get_audio_list.jsp)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%
String audioListCSV = "";
File[] audioList = new File("/provisioned/music/").listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < audioList.length; ++i) {
    File audio = audioList[i];
    if (audio.isFile()) {
        audioListCSV += "\'file:///" + audio.getAbsolutePath() + "\'";
        if (i + 1 < audioList.length) {
            audioListCSV += ",";
        }
    }
}
%>    
<vxml version="2.1">
    <form>
        <block>
            <var name="audioList" />
            <assign name="audioList" expr="[<%=audioListCSV%>]" />
            <return namelist="audioList" />
        </block>
    </form>
</vxml>
```

JSP is called subdialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version="2.1">
    <script>
        var audioList;
    </script>
    <form id="getAudioList">
        <subdialog name="get_audio_list" src="http://localhost:8080/example/get_audio_list.jsp">
            <filled>
                <assign name="audioList" expr="get_audio_list.audioList">
                <goto next="#playAudioList" />
            </filled>
        </subdialog>
    </form>
    <form id="playAudioList">
        <block>
            <prompt bargein="true">
                <foreach item="i" array="audioList">
                    <audio expr="i" />
                </foreach>
            </prompt>
        </block>
        <block>
            <disconnect />
        </block>
    </form>
</vxml>
```